# Strange error with VS2008 on Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, visual-studio-2008

We have a solution with two projects, one of them is a Silverlight 3 application which is embedded on the other ASP.NET MVC project. Just recently an error started to appear which makes the build fail. Here is the output:

```
`------ Build started: Project: DotCoquiMap, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v3.0\Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets : warning : Could not find necessary input file 'C:\Users\Michael\Documents\DotCoqui\trunk\DotCoquiMap\Bin\Debug\DotCoquiMap.dll'.
Done building project "DotCoquiMap.csproj" -- FAILED.
------ Build started: Project: DotCoquiProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /reference:C:\Users\Michael\Documents\DotCoqui\trunk\DotCoquiMap\Bin\Debug\DotCoquiMap.dll /reference:..\ExternalLibraries\itextsharp.dll /reference:..\ExternalLibraries\MvcMembership.dll /reference:..\ExternalLibraries\PagedList.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Configuration.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.Linq.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.EnterpriseServices.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Web.Abstractions.dll" /reference:..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DataVisualization\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DataVisualization.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.Mobile.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Web.Routing.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.Services.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\DotCoquiProject.dll /target:library Controllers\AccountController.cs Controllers\AdministrationController.cs Controllers\ApiController.cs Controllers\CampaignsCategoriesController.cs Controllers\CampaignsController.cs Controllers\CampaignsFormViewModel.cs Controllers\CampaignStatisticsController.cs Controllers\CampaignStatisticsDetailsViewModel.cs Controllers\ControllerHelpers.cs Controllers\CountriesController.cs Controllers\ErrorController.cs Controllers\HomeController.cs Controllers\MapController.cs Controllers\MediaController.cs Controllers\MediaViewModel.cs Controllers\NewsController.cs Controllers\OrganizationsController.cs Controllers\OrgCenterController.cs Controllers\UserAdministrationController.cs Default.aspx.cs Global.asax.cs Models\Campaigns.cs Models\CategoriesRuleValidation.cs Models\DotCoquiDBModel.designer.cs Models\DotCoquiRepository.cs Models\DQcodes.cs Models\FileRepository.cs Models\ISmtpClient.cs Models\JsonModels.cs Models\OrgCenter\IndexViewModel.cs Models\SmtpClientProxy.cs Models\Statistic.cs Models\User.cs Models\UserAdministration\DetailsViewModel.cs Models\UserAdministration\IndexViewModel.cs Models\UserAdministration\RoleViewModel.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Users\Michael\Documents\DotCoqui\trunk\DotCoquiMap\Bin\Debug\DotCoquiMap.dll' could not be found

Compile complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 2 failed, 0 skipped ==========`


And here is the errors / warnings:

Warning    2    Could not find necessary input file 'C:\Users\Michael\Documents\DotCoqui\trunk\DotCoquiMap\Bin\Debug\DotCoquiMap.dll'.    DotCoquiMap

Error    1    Metadata file 'C:\Users\Michael\Documents\DotCoqui\trunk\DotCoquiMap\Bin\Debug\DotCoquiMap.dll' could not be found    DotCoquiProject
```

The DotCoquiMap is not getting built therefore the DotCoquiProject (ASP.NET MVC) cannot find the .dll.

Now here is the really odd thing, under Windows XP the very same code compiles and runs perfectly.... under windows 7 it gives us these errors. It is the very same code, we have tested it on 3 different Win7 machines to no avail.

Help will be really really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My eyes are bleeding. Pretty code format please?

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, how can I "pretty it"?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If the text is code, select it and ctrl-k. If the text is, well, text, then surround it with <pre></pre>

Answer (score 0):

Try to recomplie all project references for DotCoquiMap project and check assembly references (or add\remove them).

Another way is rebuild each project(via right button click in solution explorer) from least to most dependent

Comment: Already tried that, the DotCoquiMap project wont build, and that is the one that DotCoquiProject depends on.

Comment: Odd thing is that exactly the same project builds normally on Windows XP just not on Win7.

Comment: Turn off UAC, reboot and try to rebuild. Also check that write permission exists to ALL output dirs

Comment: Didn't work, we are about to give up :/ and this project is for a competition :(

Answer (score 0):

Try building the project from a different directory besides your personal Documents folder.  There may be a security permissions issue.

Comment: Which other folder do you recommend? We tried doing it in the root C:\ and same error.

Comment: If that's the case, then this is probably not the issue.  Folder permissions are more restrictive in Windows 7 and Vista, so this can sometimes lead to problems that don't show up under XP.